# Mocking cassandra session object

Tags: session, junit, cassandra, mockito, powermockito

I an trying to mock the session object of cassandra which is obtained in the actual code in the following way...
`session = cluster.connect(keyspace);`

What I am looking for is "To execute the statement and return the mock session object"

I have tried the following options

1. `MemberModifier.stub(MemberMatcher.method(Cluster.class, "connect" String.class)).toReturn(session);`
2. `PowerMockito.when(cluster.connect(keyspace)).thenReturn(session);`
3. `PowerMockito.when(cluster.connect(keyspace)).thenAnswer(new Answer() { public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) { return session; } });`
4. `PowerMockito.when(cluster.connect(keyspace)).thenReturn(session);`
5. `Session testSession = cassandraService.getCassandraDBConnection();`

None of these individually or in combination seem to work.
When the relevant JUnit is executed, the error that I get is 
Stack Trace here below...

```
All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /<<ip address>>:<<port no>> (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/ip address] Cannot connect))
at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:231)
at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:77)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1414)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:162)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:333)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:283)
at com.capitalone.payments.customerprofile.service.CassandraInteractionService.getCassandraDBConnection(CassandraInteractionService.java:202)
```

Could somebody guide me here please?

(I have masked ip address and port number in stack trace)

Thanks!
-Sriram

Answer (score 4):

I guess that you want to mock the Java driver session object for testing right ?

In this case, I would recommend:

1. Use an embedded Cassandra server for unit test, see [Achilles Embedded Cassandra](https://github.com/doanduyhai/Achilles/wiki/CQL-embedded-cassandra-server) or [Cassandra Unit](https://github.com/jsevellec/cassandra-unit/wiki)
2. Use the [Stubbed Cassandra](http://scassandra-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) which simulate CQL requests and responses. This is probably the closest to achieve what you want instead of mocking

Comment: Thanks for that info doanduyhai.... So, is there no way we could mock using PowerMock or Mockito frameworks? Anyway, let me try what you said as well. Thanks again!

Comment: `Cluster` object has protected constructor so it's quite hard to mock it. In general if you need to rely on Powermock and stub everything, I would recommend to go for Stubbed Cassandra directly